# Scala -> Ruby conversion: Confusing output

Tags: ruby, lambda, functional-programming, proc

Ruby Code:

```
def fnAdd(x) 
    return ->(y) { x + y }
end

add1 = 1.method(:fnAdd)

puts add1.call(10)
```

**Output:** Proc:0x007f52658d3330@main.rb:2 (lambda)

I am having issues getting the desired output in the above code.

I'm basically trying to write the following Scala code (which calls a function that returns another function) in Ruby.

Scala Code:

```
def fnAdd (x:Int) = { 
  (y:Int) => x + y 
}

var add1 = fnAdd (1)
var add2 = fnAdd (2)

println(add1(10))
println(add2(3))
```

**Output:** 11 5

I've made an attempt at converting the code to Ruby but I'm not sure if it is correct. I don't understand the output, which appears to be some kind of proc object.

Could someone please explain what I need to change to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I'm not sure how your first example is even running, as it produces a `NameError` on my machine.</s> Regardless, `#method` is intended for accessing methods *on* specific objects. You've defined a standalone method which is already curried, not one inside of the `Fixnum` class. So you simply need to call it as a method.

```
add1 = fnAdd(1)
```

Also, Ruby has the same behavior as Scala with regard to returning the last expression in a method, so you don't need to use `return` in this case.

**Edit:**

Thanks to @JörgWMittag for pointing out a few flaws here. Defining `#fnAdd` at the top-level makes it a private instance method on `Object`. Since everything in Ruby is an object, `Fixnum` inherits from the `Object` class. Thus, `1.method(:fnAdd)` is simply giving you the `fnAdd` method without actually passing it any arguments. Thus, it still expects to be called twice.

```
fnAddMethod = 1.method(:fnAdd)
add1 = fnAddMethod.call(1)
puts add1.call(10)
```

However, this would be extremely unidiomatic, so it's best to stick with the simpler solution.

Comment: Well, methods defined at the top-level become private methods of `Object`, of which `Integer` is a subclass and `1` is an instance, so it will inherit `fnAdd`. However, it will be private (unless you execute the code in IRb, which unfortunately behaves differently)